# Wireless chipset RTL8821CE is UNCLAIMED and doesn't show in ifconfig

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, realtek-wireless

I been trying to connect my internal wireless adapter to ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS to no avail.
I download the driver with `Software & Updates` but running `lshw -C network` gives:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff
```

running `lspci` shows that its there:

```
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31e8 (rev 06)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

but it doesn't show up in `ifconfig`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlx0012fb2e0e72: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:12:fb:2e:0e:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.37.16.191/18 brd 10.37.63.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx0012fb2e0e72
       valid_lft 13799sec preferred_lft 13799sec
    inet6 fe80::2b88:c4b0:b740:cf2b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

it only shows the loopback and my Wireless Adapter dongle that i have connected
here is my ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and try again.

Comment: Wow that worked! I disabled boot before but forgot to save thanks for the help